# Can c9 workspace be used to run a website?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have an application that I created using the hugely popular and cool c9.io workspace.

c9.io workspaces go into idle mode when you haven't accessed them for sometime. This means the website that you published will no longer be running once it goes into idle mode.

I cant find any documentation about settings that would keep the workspace from going into idle mode.

Does anybody know of a way to keep the workspace active always?

Comment: Do they allow cronjobs? if so just add a cron to execute a command to keep the workspace from idling.

Answer (score 5):

I'm an engineer at Cloud9. Cloud9 is meant to be used as a development platform only, not for website hosting. Workspaces are stopped so that resources can be freed up for other users when you're not using it. That's how we're able to offer such generous plans.

If you'd like to have your website online permanently while still using Cloud9 I'd recommend buying a cheap VPS from any hosting provider and creating a SSH workspace in Cloud9 connecting to that VPS.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Thought i can use it for web hosting too and that was the reason i was looking for documentation :)